# Instagram Signed Call in Python

Tags: python, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to achieve a signed call to Instagram API in Python. Currently my headers looks like this :

```py
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8A293 Safari/6531.22.7'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': user_agent,
    "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}
```

I tried several permutations on the instructions given at [this page (Restrict API Requests @ instagram)](https://instagram.com/developer/restrict-api-requests/#), including the **HMAC method** and enabling **"Enforce Signed Header"** in my API settings page.

But I keep getting either a `headers not found` or `403` error. I just cant figure out how to properly code `X-Insta-Forwarded-For`

Can you please help with how to pass Signed call with header in Python?
Much appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

This should do it for you. You'll need the Crypto python library as well.

```
import requests
from Crypto.Hash import HMAC, SHA256

#change these accordingly
client_secret = "mysecret"
client_ip = "127.0.0.1"

hmac = HMAC.new(client_secret, digestmod=SHA256)
hmac.update(client_ip)
signature = hmac.hexdigest()

header_string = "%s|%s" % (client_ip, signature)

headers = {
    "X-Insta-Forwarded-For" : header_string,
    #and the rest of your headers
}

#or use requests.post or del since that's the 
#only time that this header is used...just 
#conveying the concept
resp = requests.get(insta_url, headers=headers)
```

If you test it with the example that's given on the reference you listed, you can verify that you get the correct hash using this method

```
ip = "200.15.1.1"
secret = "6dc1787668c64c939929c17683d7cb74"
hmac = HMAC.new(secret, digestmod=SHA256)
hmac.update(ip)
signature = hmac.hexdigest() 
# should be 7e3c45bc34f56fd8e762ee4590a53c8c2bbce27e967a85484712e5faa0191688
```

Per the reference docs - "To enable this setting, edit your OAuth Client configuration and mark the Enforce signed header checkbox." So make sure you have done that too

Comment: Hello, Much appreciated for the reponse... unfortunately, I am getting the error NameError: name 'insta_url' is not defined. If I remove the line, then the restrictions get enforced (30 likes/hour, 15 comments/hour)... How to get around this? Please help...

Comment: the insta_url was just for demonstration. It should look something like https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/<media ID here>/likes. So if the media ID was 123456 then I would construct `insta_url` like so:

`insta_url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/123456/relationship"`

Note that I'm going to be using the "relationship" api, which only supports POSTing with the signed header, so your request should be done like so

`requests.post(insta_url, headers=headers)`

Comment: have a look at the "Enforce signed header" section of the api docs you posted to see the available methods supporting the signed header. There are more code demos further down the page and you can even test via curl

Comment: Thank you for the response... This is working well now... Instead of requests method, I used urllib and urllib2 (just could not figure out requests!)... The critical part is to enable BOTH check boxes in the Instagram API page to ensure one passes the signed headers successfully to take advantage of the signed call limits (which are more than unsigned calls limits)... cheers :)

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear it. Could you please make my post as the answer :)